# Equation of Vertical Plane that passes through point P in direction of unit vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

I am learning about directional derivatives right now. In attempt to gain a better geometrical understanding of the concept, I am trying to graph the surface and the vertical plane that passes through point P on the surface in direction of the given unit vector.

For instance, if the curve is the function $z = xy^3 - x^2$, the unit vector is $<cos(\frac{\pi}{3}),sin(\frac{\pi}{3}) >$ and the point is (1,2) - what would be the equation of the vertical plane?

Comment: What do you mean be "a plane passing through $P$ in the direction of the unit vector"? Do you mean that the unit vector lies in the plane? (Also, it's strange how the point and the vector are 2d but I guess that probably makes sense in the context of the vertical plane.) Can you give a simple example like a sphere to show what you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, it makes sense when I think of it in terms of directional derivatives (the plane and surface intersect to form the curve whose derivative is the directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector).

Comment: @amd How did you figure out the normal?

Comment: Oops. Wrong normal. You need a vector in the $x$-$y$ plane that’s orthogonal to the direction in which you’re taking the derivative, so just rotate your unit vector 90 degrees to get either $\left\langle\sin\frac\pi3,-\cos\frac\pi3,0\right\rangle$ or its negative. Another way to get this normal is to take the cross product of your unit vector (lifted into $\mathbf R^3$) and the $z$-axis.